# How to add hours to date considering DST

Tags: c#, .net, time, timezone

How to add hours to date considering DST ?

We have time shift at 27 of October, so i expect to get 19(or 21) hour in result.

How can i do that ?

```
  var test = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2018, 10, 26, 20, 0, 0));
  var test2 = test.AddHours(48);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest approach is to convert to UTC, add the 48 hours there, then convert back. That way you apply the appropriate time zone offset at each point. For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var test = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2018, 10, 26, 20, 0, 0));
        var test2 = test.AddHours(48);
        var test3 = test.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(48).ToLocalTime();
        Console.WriteLine(test2);
        Console.WriteLine(test3);
    }
}
```

Results in the London time zone:

```
28/10/2018 20:00:00 +01:00
28/10/2018 19:00:00 +00:00
```

Note that in some cases the original local time could be skipped or ambiguous though - you should consider what to do then. I'd personally (for obvious reasons) recommend my [Noda Time project](https://nodatime.org) for this instead, where there are more types to represent the different kinds of value you'd work with. Decisions like how to deal with skipped/ambiguous times are more obvious because you basically *have* to make them.

Answer (score 3):

Convert DateTime to UTC:

```
var dateLocal = new DateTime(2018, 10, 26, 20, 0, 0);
var dateUTC = dateLocal.ToUniversalTime();
```

Add the hours:

```
dateUTC = dateUTC.AddHours(48);
```

Convert back to local time:

```
dateLocal = dateUTC.ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in way to check for DST, you could do arithmitic based on that similar to:

```
var test = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2018, 11, 4, 0, 0, 0));
var newTime = test.AddHours(2);

if (test.LocalDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime() && 
     !newTime.LocalDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime())
        {
            test = test.AddHours(-1);
        }
```

You might also look at [nodatime](https://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/arithmetic).

Comment: That assumes DST is always 1 hour, and always in that direction. It's best to avoid assumptions as far as possible with time work.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, and prefer your answer too. I left out any case other than the one example half undecided if anything other than references to Nodatime really made sense if I was going to add cases.